# Apply multiple filters to a table

Tags: codeigniter, filter

In Codeigniter, I have a table, and I am trying to apply multiple filters on it at the same time.

For example, let's say I make 5 checkboxes and a button "apply", each of the checkboxes applies a filter to my table like so:

1. When I click on first check box, I want my url to change from `localhost/ci` to `localhost/ci/filter1`.
2. When I click both `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`, I want my url to change to `localhost/ci/filter1/filter2` and so on.

Is there any way to do this without using jQuery, or AJAX?

Comment: Could you show us what code you've already written?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your post a little bit to make it easier to read. Also, I wrapped your code-like text in `'s. For more information on highlighting, you can visit [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Stack Overflow does not really like "Thank You" or "PS" at the end of posts, so I removed them. Try to make your post helpful to others, too. Please edit in what you've tried so far, and why it doesn't work. Good luck solving your problem!

Comment: You are doing it in a wrong way, you should put your check box in a form. Use query string instead of URI.

Comment: You cant do this automagically without JavaScript but if you can submit the form then you can handle the data and redirect browser to an url you construct